# Refresh Firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, page-refresh

I have a tab bar controller with four view controllers. In one of the view controllers, I perform lots of edits and when I make the edits, I would like for the view controller to display those edits. Right now in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

I have implemented a function that every time the view controller appears, it refreshes. But I don't like this and I think it's slightly annoying.

Is there a way I can check Firebase to see if an edit was made and then refresh only if an edit is made?

Answer (score 1):

You could append the results of your Firebase Observation to an Array and every 10 seconds or so reload the Firebase DataBase fetch and check if the array is equal to what you've found. Then set the array as the new fetch's results.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can check Firebase to see if an edit was made and
>   then refresh only if an edit is made?

You could use Firebase Cloud Functions and Cloud Messaging.

[Here are the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) for writing a cloud function that performs whenever a specific Database branch is edited.

And [here is an example project](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications) by Firebase that shows how to send a notification when a specific database branch is edited.

Then, when a notification is sent, you can have your AppDelegate make the appropriate viewcontroller(s) refresh the appropriate screens.

Comment: Second link is a github 404.

Comment: @jessi My bad, I've fixed it in my original answer, and here it is again: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications